# Android Camera2 API Audio Video Is Off Sync

Tags: android, audio-recording, video-recording, android-camera2

So I'm writing a plugin to be able to record a video using the Android Camera2 API. I was able to successfully record video only and it works as intended.

But when I add audio into the mix I get this weird bug where, it works fine while recording (no errors or anything), but when I play it from the explorer, the video starts frozen with only the audio playing first, and once the audio is over, the video starts playing. This was happening on my phone, the Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge. I tested this on my colleague's phone, the Samsung Galaxy Note 4, and it worked fine on that with no issues. Both are running Android 6.0.1.

This is my code,

```
private void StartRecord () {
    try {
        SetupMediaRecorder();

        mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mConvertor.GetSurface());
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mMediaRecorder.getSurface());

        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(mConvertor.GetSurface(), mMediaRecorder.getSurface()),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                        try {
                            mCaptureSession = session;
                            mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
                            mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
                                    null, mBackgroundHandler);
                        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {

                    }
                }, mBackgroundHandler);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void SetupMediaRecorder () throws IOException {
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    //I've tried DEFAULT and CAMCORDER as well but it didn't help.

    //Someone suggested CamcorderProfile, but that didn't help either.
    //CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    //camcorderProfile.fileFormat = MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4;
    //camcorderProfile.videoBitRate = 10000000;
    //camcorderProfile.videoFrameRate = 30;
    //camcorderProfile.videoCodec = MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP;
    //camcorderProfile.audioCodec = MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC;
    //camcorderProfile.videoFrameWidth = mVideoSize.getWidth();
    //camcorderProfile.videoFrameHeight = mVideoSize.getHeight();

    //mMediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);

    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mVideoFileName);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);

    //TODO: Set the correct orientation hint
    mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(0);

    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
}

public void StopRecording () {
    mMediaRecorder.stop();
    mMediaRecorder.reset();
    StartPreview();
}
```

I've searched all over the internet for a solution but nothing has worked so far. I'm trying out different settings while settings up the MediaRecorder but I'm not sure. Can anyone tell me if the issue is in the way I stopped the MediaRecorder? First time I'm writing an android plugin, so I'm not really sure if I messed up. I followed a video tutorial to write this code, but even the official sample code for Camera2 API has the same error so maybe it's not me?

Any help would be grateful, thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution? As today the issue still happens in several Samsung devices.